# Dates taking different format in javascript code

Tags: javascript, asp.net, date

I want to validation in javascript by comparing `DATES` and `TIME`.

I want in the **dd/MM/yyyy** format but I dont know which format it is taking. I debugged the js code and got the format. Below is the screenshot which is giving me any other date while I am inserting `TODAYS` date.

[image: Image1]

and below is the code:-

```
function ValidateRecord() {
        var StrPriError = "";



        if (document.getElementById('TextBox1').value == "" || document.getElementById('TextBox2').value == "" || document.getElementById('TextBox3').value == "" || document.getElementById('TextBox4').value == "") {
            StrPriError += "Dates cannot be blank \n";
        }
        else {
            var dt1 = new Date(document.getElementById('TextBox1').value + " " + document.getElementById('DrpTime').value);
            var dt2 = new Date(document.getElementById('TextBox2').value + " " + document.getElementById('DrpTime3').value);
            var dt3 = new Date(document.getElementById('TextBox3').value + " " + document.getElementById('DrpTime4').value);
            var dt4 = new Date(document.getElementById('TextBox4').value + " " + document.getElementById('DrpTime5').value);

            if (dt1.getTime() == dt2.getTime() || dt1.getTime() == dt3.getTime() || dt1.getTime() == dt4.getTime() || dt2.getTime() == dt3.getTime() || dt2.getTime() == dt4.getTime() || dt3.getTime() == dt4.getTime()) {
                StrPriError += "Dates and Times cannot be same \n";
            }
            else {
               // StrPriError += "Good to go \n";
            }

            if (dt2.getTime() < dt1.getTime()) {
                StrPriError += "Reminder 2 cannot be less than reminder 1 \n";
            }

            if (dt3.getTime() < dt1.getTime()) {
                StrPriError += "Reminder 3 cannot be less than reminder 1 \n";
            }

            if (dt4.getTime() < dt1.getTime()) {
                StrPriError += "Reminder 4 cannot be less than reminder 1 \n";
            }
            if (dt3.getTime() < dt2.getTime()) {
                StrPriError += "Reminder 3 cannot be less than reminder 2 \n";
            }

            if(dt4.getTime() < dt2.getTime()) {
                StrPriError += "Reminder 4 cannot be less than reminder 2 \n";
            }

            if (dt4.getTime() < dt3.getTime()) {
                StrPriError += "Reminder 4 cannot be less than reminder 3 \n";
            }
        }
        if (StrPriError != "") {
            alert(StrPriError);
            return false;
        }
        else {
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Also see the HTML:-

```
<td colspan="1px" style="width: 13%" class="field">
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Width="80" Enabled="false"></asp:TextBox>
                <cc3:Calendar ID="Calendar1" runat="server" DatePickerMode="true" TextBoxId="TextBox1"
                    DatePickerImagePath="../../Images/icon2.gif" CultureName="en-GB">
                </cc3:Calendar>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="DrpTime" runat="server" Width="65px">
                    <asp:ListItem Value="09:00">09:00</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="13:00">13:00</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="17:00">17:00</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="21:00">21:00</asp:ListItem>
                </asp:DropDownList>
            </td>
            <td colspan="1px" style="width: 13%" class="field">
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" Width="80" Enabled="false"></asp:TextBox>
                <cc3:Calendar ID="Calendar2" runat="server" DatePickerMode="true" TextBoxId="TextBox2"
                    DatePickerImagePath="../../Images/icon2.gif" CultureName="en-GB">
                </cc3:Calendar>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="DrpTime3" runat="server" Width="65px">
                    <asp:ListItem Value="09:00">09:00</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="13:00">13:00</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="17:00">17:00</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="21:00">21:00</asp:ListItem>
                </asp:DropDownList>
            </td>
```

Because of this I am  not able to do validation properly. Any suggestion how to achieve this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily achieve this by using [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) ,

```
var dt1 = moment(document.getElementById('TextBox1').value + " " + document.getElementById('DrpTime').value, "DD/MM/yyyy HH:mm");
```

Comment: do I need to install that `moment.js` plugin ??

Comment: You have to include moment.js script in your page

Comment: can you give me the link for the same, as most of the sites are block on my end.

Comment: i tried like that by inserting today's date but I am getting value as `Mon Feb 01 2016 09:00:00 GMT +0530` Time and Year are correct, just date is taking one week back. **WHY** ?

Comment: What are the values of document.getElementById('TextBox1').value?  and document.getElementById('DrpTime').value?

Comment: The values are `"09/02/2016"` and `"09:00"` respectively

Comment: but when I check the dates in alert I get different dates which I mentioned. is it something related to `moment` js ?

Comment: Problem was format should be "DD/MM/yyyy HH:mm", the "dd" was simple, once you use upper case it should work (updated the answer)

Comment: yeah, got that. anyways thanks for the solutionn, +1

Answer (score 2):

```
  var monthNames = [
                       "January", "February", "March",
                       "April", "May", "June", "July",
                       "August", "September", "October",
                       "November", "December"
                       ];

                var dd =  new Date(document.getElementById('TextBox1').value + " " + document.getElementById('DrpTime').value);

                output.value = dd.getDate() + ' ' + monthNames[dd.getMonth()] + ' ' + dd.getFullYear() + ' ' + dd.getHours() + ':' + dd.getMinutes() + ':' + dd.getSeconds();
```

I think the above code will helps you.

Comment: let me try and check

Comment: getting error as `Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'output' is undefined`

Comment: what is the actual string value coming out of the date textbox

Comment: @coder I just mentioned `output.value` for you reference. You just edit the code and assign the output where you want.

Comment: I want to check first whether it is taking proper format or not. i will update the question for your reference.just show  me how to do that

Comment: I think your code is correct. What is the need of formatting date here? because you did not show that anywhere...

Comment: Tell me is your code is working perfect are you getting any errors? if yes, where?

Comment: yes it is working sometime perfect and sometime not. I am not sure